# R- How to obtain a US Map with state boundaries using ggplot and sf, without using ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Over the weekend, I have been trying and failing to create a map of the US with state boundaries that I can draw a scatter plot on. The easiest way to do this previously seems to have been to do it with ggmaps, but google seems to have changed their APIs so I would have to enable them manually by entering a billing credit card, so that's not an option. The best alternative I could get is by using the sf library and the following code that I found in a tutorial, and it gives me the following plot without the state boundaries:

```
world <- getMap(resolution = "low")
class(world)
world <- st_as_sf(world)
class(world)

locdata= subset(pkdata,longitude!="NA" &latitude!='NA')

ggplot(data = world)+
  geom_sf(fill="grey")+
  geom_jitter(data= locdata, aes(longitude,latitude,col= age), alpha=0.5)+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(min(locdata$longitude)+37, max(locdata$longitude)), 
           ylim = c(min(locdata$latitude)+6, max(locdata$latitude)-10))+
  xlab("Longitude")+ 
  ylab("Latitude")+
  ggtitle("Police killing locations 2015-16")
```

[image]

Does someone know how I could sf or any other package to get a plot of the US with state boundaries without using ggmaps?

I have also found another page that seems to suggest using the code:

```
us <- map_data("state")
gg <- ggplot()+
  geom_map(data=us, map=us,aes(long, lat, map_id=region))
```

But strangely, even after loading the state maps correctly, I get the following error when trying to run this: 
"Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x, y"

Comment: No, that's the "modern" rewrite of ggplot2 and it's just a warning. If it makes a map for you then why not use it?

Comment: Check the urbnmpr package. Though if you want to have points in AK and HI you will have to do some wrangling.

Comment: @hrbmstr If you are referring to the last bit of code I mentioned, I too am not sure why it doesn't use lon and lat as the x and y coordinates. They seem to be there just fine in my working space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))

ggplot(usa) +
  geom_sf(color = "#2b2b2b", fill = "white", size=0.125) +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs"), datum = NA) +
  ggthemes::theme_map()
```

[image]

Comment: usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map("state", fill=TRUE, plot =FALSE))

Seems to have been the missing line that I needed

Comment: You'll need to do some investigation for how to get the points on the albers projection. A good path is to convert a data frame of X/Y coordinates to an `sf` object with longlat projection. Otherwise just remove the `crs` param in `coord_sf`

Comment: e.g. https://gist.github.com/andrewheiss/0580d6ffec37b6bc4d0ae8e77bf30956